# How can I get the value from Java class to JS function through ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, struts2

**Jsp Page**

```
function emailValidate() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var url = "emailValidate.action?email=" + email;

    $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                async : false,

                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);                      
                    alert($('#ajaxResponse').text(jsonResponse.isUserAllow));

                     if (....) {
                        alret("This Email-Id is alreay registered.");
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                    } 
                },
                failure : function(data) {
                    alert('Server side failure with status code '
                            + response.status);
                }
            })
```

**Java Class :**

```
   public String execute() {

    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    email = request.getParameter("email");

    int isUserAllow = 0;

    try {
        EmailValidationDaoImp evl = new EmailValidationDaoImp();
        isUserAllow = evl.emailValidation(email);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.getWriter() .write("isUserAllow:"+isUserAllow);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in RegAction.java : " + e);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

I had use Struts2. 
I want to send back the value of isUserAllow  to the JS function so i can put it in the if condition.

Comment: Don't ***ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever***

Comment: ... **never, ever, never** use `async : false`

Comment: Aaand, it's `alert` not `alret`, and `error` not `failure` and you don't seem to have anything named `jsonResponse` or even `response`, it's all named `data`

Comment: also use `data.isUserAllow` for particular field

Comment: As you said i have improved by as beflow.

Comment: function emailValidate() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

  var url = "emailValidate.action?email=" + email;

  $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : url,
   dataType : 'json',

   success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (data.isUserAllow == 1) {
     alert("This Email-Id is alreay registered.");
    } else {
     document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }
   },
   error : function(data) {
    alert('Server side failure with status code ');

   }
  })

Comment: Now its giving Server side failure with status code

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

In your java File: **instead of this,**

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.getWriter() .write("isUserAllow:"+isUserAllow);
```

**You can use the below code**

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(isUserAllow);
```

**and remove the `return type("success")`.**

In your **`js`** file you can modify as shown below:

```
      success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);                    
                 if (data == 0) {
                    alert("This Email-Id is alreay registered.");
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                } 
            },
```

Comment: Just don't do that.

Comment: @Poori Its not worked. but any how i resolved it that how its work with struts2 and now its working .